# FastAPI reload stops during reload

Tags: gunicorn, fastapi

I created a FastAPI container for my app based on Ubuntu22 and run it with `--reload` but I do not see the reloads finish.

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--reload", "--access-logfile", "-", "--error-logfile", "-", "--capture-output", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "app.main:app"]
```

```
[2022-11-09 21:18:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-11-09 21:18:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2022-11-09 21:18:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2022-11-09 21:18:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2022-11-09 21:18:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Started server process [8]
[2022-11-09 21:18:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2022-11-09 21:18:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Application startup complete.


[2022-11-09 21:18:45 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker reloading: /app/main.py modified

No output after this point
```

and the API seems to not be changing when it runs, still operating in the state the server started. Where can I look closer to check if it really is reloading and how to fix this? I see no error during the reload. It just stays how it is...

EDIT:
Based on Michael's comment to check the logs.

My logs show this during initial start

```
INFO:app.main:FAST API LOADING...
INFO:app.main:FAST API LOADING...2
INFO:app.main:FAST API LOADING...3
INFO:app.main:FAST API LOADED
```

and I would expect them to show the same after the reload is triggered but it does not appear in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

To see if the file is reloaded put a print("loaded main.py") or any other log statement as the first line in your main.py.
If you see the log message it was reloaded.

Comment: Good idea, in fact I had one in there but didnt check. See my edits...